# what is the distribution OS of docker image

Tags: docker

*How can find distribution OS of an official docker image into docker hub ?*

I want custom my building of image docker into my Dockerfile but if I don't know which OS is running, I have lot of error that can't resolve inficiently.

I try :

- The docker hub website hasn't given this information
- The inspect layer of image with 'dive' program don't give this information
- I know that exist this OS ; Alpine, Distroless but I don't know how knowing which used

Answer (score 0):

whatever docker image you are using for finding OS distribution image builds with is, login to your running container and executes: 
`cat /etc/*release`